# Bandwidth of a complex pole

Tags: frequency-spectrum, transfer-function, frequency-response, bandwidth

Text from "Fundamentals of Speech Recognition (Rabiner)".

> A complex pole of the LPC model spectrum can be expressed as $Z_i =
> > r_i \cdot e^{j \omega_i} $, where $r_i$ and $\omega_i$ are the radius
> and frequency of the complex pole, respectively.
>
> The bandwidth of the complex pole is related to the radius by,
>
> $ B_i = - \log(r_i) \cdot f_s/π$

My understanding of bandwidth is that it is the frequency range outside which the signal power drops by 3dB.

What does bandwidth of a complex pole mean? How is the 3dB or any other metric incorporated in the given formula for bandwidth $B_i$ ?

Comment: Note that this is an approximation, valid only for $r_i \approx 1$. I’ll answer shortly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My understanding of bandwidth is that it is the frequency range outside which the signal power drops by 3dB.

That is the usual definition, yes.  A better phrasing may be "drops by 3dB from the peak power".

> What does bandwidth of a complex pole mean?

That, compared to that pole's frequency of least effect, the contribution to the signal's attenuation (or it's loss of gain) *of that pole* is 3dB down.

> How is the 3dB or any other metric incorporated in the given formula for bandwidth $B_i$ ?

It's difficult to explain without dragging in half of DSP theory, so you may find this explanation a bit dense.

I'm going to introduce a bit of common DSP notation here: if you see $H(\omega)$, it denotes the system's response to a single-frequency complex signal:
$$H(\omega) = \left . H(z) \right |_{z = e^{j \omega}} \tag 1$$
Yes, the DSP crowd *is* playing fast and loose with the notation here.  Sorry-not-sorry.

In order to isolate the effect of the one pole from the rest of the system, assume that your system transfer function is equal to
$$H(z) = H_{tr}(z) H_i(z) = H_{tr}(z) \frac {1 - r_i}{z - Z_i} \tag 2$$
where $H_i(z)$ is the effect of your pole and $H_{tr}(z)$ is the rest of the transfer function.

< Snip some extraneous material here, which means that equation (3) is lost >

Consider $H_i$ by itself, when it is excited by a tone at a frequency offset from $\omega_i$:
$$H_i(\omega_i + \Delta \omega) = 
\frac {1 - r_i} {e^{j(\omega_i + \Delta \omega)} - Z_i} =  
\frac {1 - r_i} {e^{j(\omega_i + \Delta \omega)} - r_i e^{j \omega_i}} =
\frac {1 - r_i} {e^{j\omega_i} \left ( e^{j \Delta \omega} - r_i \right ) } 
\tag 4$$

Observe that at $\Delta \omega = 0$,
$$\left | H_i(\omega_i + \Delta \omega) \right | = 1 \tag 5$$

Observe that for $\Delta \omega \ll 1$,
$$e^{j \Delta \omega} \simeq 1 + j \Delta \omega \tag 6$$

Using (6), for sufficiently small $\Delta \omega$,
$$\left | H_i(\omega_i + \Delta \omega) \right | \simeq 
\left | \frac {1 - r_i}{1 - r_i + j\Delta \omega} \right | \tag 7$$

Now assume that $-\log r_i \ll 1$ (note that $0 < r_i < 1$).  Then $r_i \simeq 1 + \log r_i$. (7) becomes
$$\begin{aligned}
\left | H_i(\omega_i + \Delta \omega) \right | &\simeq
\left | \frac {1 - (1 + \log r_i)}{1 - (1 + \log r_i) + j\Delta \omega} \right | \\ &=
\left | \frac {- \log r_i}{- \log r_i + j\Delta \omega} \right | \\ &=
\frac {- \log r_i}{\sqrt{\log^2 r_i + (\Delta \omega)^2}}
\end{aligned}
\tag 8$$

When $\Delta \omega = \pm \log r_i$, (8) becomes
$$\left | H_i(\omega_i + \Delta \omega) \right | \simeq 
\frac 1 {\sqrt 2} \tag 9$$
i.e., for $\omega = \omega_i \pm \log r_i$, the response is 3dB down from the peak.

To get this into the author's notation, observe that the sampled-time frequency $\omega$ is related to the real-world frequency as
$$\omega = 2 \pi \frac f {f_s} \tag {10}$$
Solving for $f$:
$$f = \frac {\omega f_s}{2 \pi} \tag {11}$$

To find the real-world bandwidth, plug our 3dB down points into (11):
$$B_i = 
\left( \left(\omega_i + \log r_i \right) - \left( \omega_i - \log r_i \right) \right) \frac {f_s}{2 \pi} =
\log r_i \frac{f_s}{\pi}
\tag {12}$$

Which is what your book's author so blithely wrote in one sentence.

Comment: Equation 3 is missing. This is such a beautiful answer. The only thing that bothers me is the formulation for Hi(z) (effect of i-th pole). The denominator (z - Zi) makes total sense. At the end of the day whatever denominator H(z) has, it can be broken into (z-Z1)*(z-Z2)*.. and so on ; that is what defines a pole. However, I can't reason (1-ri) in the numerator. Closer the pole is to the origin, greater is the emphasis by the filter?

Comment: It’s to have unity gain at the resonant frequency (equation 5), and to make it easier to derive 9) from there. Tim’s beautiful answer holds as well with $Hi(z)=\frac{1}{z−Zi}$ but with some tweaks. The normalization makes it easier to follow.

Comment: Nice answer!!!!

Comment: Equations (7) and (8), are you sure this should be the |magnitude| response? If so, I wouldn't expect the imaginary $j\Delta_{\omega}$ in the denominator. Either you meant to write the frequency response instead, in which case $e^{j\omega_i}$ should still be in the denominator as well (and disappears when the magnitude is taken), or you simply forgot the $||$ on the denominators of (7) and (8)...

Comment: I forgot to indicate the absolute values appropriately.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Tim's answer is a very nice derivation of the approximation in the discrete-time domain.

Two additions to his fantastic answer:

#### Derivation of the approximation in the continuous-time domain

It's also possible to get to the approximation in the continuous-time domain: see [this reference](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/%7Ejos/fp/Relating_Pole_Radius_Bandwidth.html)

#### Calculating the $-3\texttt{dB}$ bandwidth

We can actually calculate the $-3\texttt{dB}$ bandwidth *exactly* for any value of $r$ and show that the approximation $-\log(r)\frac{f_s}{\pi}$ is valid for $r$ *close to* $1$.

Starting with the *normalized* transfer function of a complex one-pole resonator:
$$H(z) = \frac{1-r}{1-pz^{-1}}$$ where $p = re^{j\omega_c}$ and $\omega_c = 2\pi\frac{f_c}{f_s}$ is the resonant normalized angular frequency.

The magnitude response can be calculated as:
$$
|H(\omega)| = \frac{|1-r|}{|1-re^{j(\omega_c-\omega)}|} = \frac{1-r}{\sqrt{1 - 2r\cos(\omega_c-\omega) + r^2}}
$$

As in Tim's answer, note that $|H(\omega_c)| = 1$

The $-3\,\tt{dB}$ bandwidth $\Delta_{\omega}$ is such that $$|H(\omega)| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$ Let's solve this:
\begin{align}
\frac{1-r}{\sqrt{1 - 2r\cos(\frac{\Delta_{\omega}}{2}) + r^2}} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
2(1-r)^2 &= 1 - 2r\cos(\frac{\Delta_{\omega}}{2}) + r^2\\
2\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{r(4-r)-1}{2r}\right) &= \Delta_{\omega}\\
\end{align}

So now we have an exact expression for the bandwidth with respect to $r$:
$$ \Delta_{\omega} = 2\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{r(4-r)-1}{2r}\right)$$
Let's verify that this aligns with the approximation $\Delta_{\omega} = -2\log(r)$ for values of $r$ *close to $1$*:

*Note that to get to real-world frequency, these two expressions should be multiplied by $\frac{f_s}{2\pi}$*

[image]

Comment: I satisfied myself (on the log approximation; area under the graph intuition) with https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3253689/944228  .But now you have offered exact bandwidth's formulation.  Absolutely cool! Thanks.